# why can't I parsing value 'fields' in my code?

Tags: android, json

When I run my app, In logcat, "Problem parsing the earthquake Json results
    org.json.JSONException: No value for fields"

Could you check my JSON code..? I'm beginner of JSON Parsing, So I searched a lot inf But I'm not sure about my code.

[image: This is my Urls...]

```
public class Utils {

private static List<News> extractFromJson(String newsJSON) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newsJSON)) {
        return null;
    }

    List<News> news = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        // Create a JSONObject from the JSON response string
        JSONObject baseJsonResponse = new JSONObject(newsJSON);
        JSONObject response = baseJsonResponse.getJSONObject("response");
        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("results");


        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject currentNews = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject fields = currentNews.getJSONObject("fields");

            Drawable thumbnail = LoadImageFromUrl (fields.getString("thumbnail"));

            String section = currentNews.getString("sectionName");
            String title = currentNews.getString("webTitle");
            String url = currentNews.getString("webUrl");
            String date = currentNews.getString("webPublicationDate");

            news.add(new News( section, title, url, date,thumbnail));
        }
        return news;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("Utils", "Problem parsing the news Json results", e);
    }
    return null;
    }

private static Drawable LoadImageFromUrl(String imageurl) {
    Drawable drawable = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;

    try {
        inputStream = new URL(imageurl).openStream();
        drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(inputStream, null);
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return drawable;
}
```

}

Comment: if you print out the json object fields, what is printed?

Comment: Make sure you have `fields` jsonobject value in all the jsonobject of results array. Check through entire json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this to validate**

Problem occur may be you dont have a field `jsonobject` in your json list. It may be not present in the some of other `jsonobjects`. So check if `jsonobject` has actual field `jsonobject` before parsing.

> Use this condition whenever your json value might give null sometimes.

```
  if(currentNews.has("fields"))
           {
             JSONObject fields = currentNews.getJSONObject("fields");
           }
          else
           {
              Log.d("JSON_TAG","NO FIELD JSON OBJECT");
           }
```

Comment: Welcome glad to help happy coding :)